# Dynamically fill aggregate function in Mongoosejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a NodeJS / Express application which stores personas in a MongoDB. I would like to count specific field in the database, so that I can report on a dashboard.

So for example, some users have their firstname filled in, others have their postalcode filled in. I want to report on the percentage of users with their firstname filled in.

For this I have setup a controller, which makes a call to the Persona model. Now I want to dynamically aggregate on specific fields.

The way I solve it right now, is by filling a match variable with a switch statement:

```
countField: function countField(field, cb) {
switch(field) {
  case 'personal_firstname':
    var match = {$match: {
        "personal_firstname":  { $exists: true }
    }};
    break;
    break;
  case 'address_postalcode':
    var match = {$match: {
        "address_postalcode":  { $exists: true }
    }};
    break;
    break;
  default:
    var match = {$match: {
        "personal_firstname":  { $exists: true }
    }}; 
}

return this.aggregate([
    match,
    {$group: {
        _id: null, 
        totalfields: {$sum: 1}
    }}
], cb)
```

}

However, it would be better if I could dynamically insert the "field" argument in my aggregate function. However, mongooseJS does not allow me this.

Is there a way to dynamically insert the mongooseJS aggregate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to construct the match object dynamically, as in the following:

```
countField: function countField(field, cb) {    
    var match = { "$match": {} };
    if (!field) field = "personal_firstname";
    match["$match"][field] = { $exists: true }

    return this.aggregate([ match,
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": null, 
                "totalfields": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
        }
    ], cb)
}
```